# How can I add a scrollbar to an iphone site?

Tags: iphone, css, scrollbar

I created a mini-version of a site that's been optimized for the iPhone, but on one of the pages, I have a scrollbar in a container, and it shows up when looking at it on the computer, but not at all on the iphone...  Is there some kind of special magic that I need or something?  The css is simple:

```
#container {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use some javascript, such as [jScrollPane](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html), or tell users to use two fingers to scroll. There are no traditional scrollbars on the iPhone.